# How to detect a redirection in Glide v4 / OkHttp3?

Tags: android, okhttp, android-glide

Using Glide v4 and OkHttp3, how can I detect a redirection and load another url when it happens?

My usecase: I use the Glide v4 library with OkHttp3 to download pictures in my app. Sometimes when a picture is not available, a redirection is performed by the server to provide another picture instead of the one I originaly wanted. I can see it in my browser because when I request url A, I finally land on url B with the second picture. When that happens I want to instead load url C that is derived from url A (so not a static url).

At the moment I can detect the redirection using an OkHttp3 Interceptor:

```
public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
    String requestUrl = chain.request().url().toString();
    Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    String responseUrl = response.request().url().toString();

    boolean redirect = !requestUrl.equals(responseUrl);
    if (redirect) {
        Timber.d("Detected redirection");
    }

    return response;
}
```

but then I don't know how to cleanly load url C. I don't see how I can load another url in the interceptor, and if I throw an IOException to handle the error later in a Glide RequestListener it will just result in a GlideException so I can't determine why it was throw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up with is pretty ugly: the request interceptor I showed in the question raise an IOException when a redirection is detected. I will then use a GlideListener to detect the error, and load the url C. The ugly part is that in the GlideListener I can't determine the cause of the error, it can be a redirection but it can also be a network error or anything else.

A cleaner version of this solution can probably be achieved with a custom OkHttpUrlLoader but it's too much code for my simple usecase.

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp should be automatically redirecting by default and loading the final content.  See OkHttpClient.Builder.followRedirects.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#followRedirects-boolean-

My own testing suggests this is working, e.g.

```
$ oksocial 'https://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ/maxresdefault.jpg'
```

For detecting it, I assume your interceptor is registered via addInterceptor instead of addNetworkInterceptor.  Is that correct?

It is also worth ensuring the redirect is via a 30X response and not via a HTML refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution in Glide v4 / OkHttp3

```
String redirect = response.header("location");
if(redirect != null && !request.url().toString().equals(redirect)) {
    // if redirected your code here
}
```